# Mongodb not limiting output when using limit in the pipeline

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, mongodb-query, mongo-dart

```
      final pipeline = AggregationPipelineBuilder()
      .addStage(Match(where
          .eq('_id', ObjectId.fromHexString(authDetails.subject))
          .map['\$query']))
      .addStage(Match(
          where.eq('messages.username', theirUsername).map['\$query']))
      .addStage(Project({
        '_id': 0, //You can use as:'customer' instead of this keyword.
        'messages': Filter(input: '\$messages', cond: {
          '\$eq': ['\$\$this.username', theirUsername]
        }).build(),
      }))
      .build();
```

No matter where I add limit(5) I get back the same results. I've tried asking a few people but nobody seems to know how to fix it, But, trying on here, hopefully someone knows mongodb enough in dart to suggest a solution

Comment: How have you tried to add the limit?

Comment: anywhere the complier would not complain while coding, so like anywhere i didn't get an error, typically on the end, i've tried it before the maps both limit(5) and Limit(5), all return either null or the same result as if there was no limit

Comment: does limit only apply to the top level documents? would I use slice instead since the messages are nested inside of a document under the field messages?

Comment: yes, limit applies to the top-level documents